# Migrate DHCP from Cisco to Windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, cisco, database, dhcp, migration

Is is possible to seamlessly migrate from DHCP on Cisco routers to a Windows server?  All my searches give me tips on migrating from 2003 to 2008 DHCP but nothing on Cisco to Windows.

Comment: You mention nothing of your current setup.  Are you looking to export your current settings?

Comment: Do you have dhcp helper addresses on any routers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably a number of ways to do this. One way would be to set up the DHCP service on the server to match the Cisco, including scope, reservations, options, etc. Leave the scope unactivated until you're ready to make the switch. When you're ready to make the switch, shut down the DHCP service on the Cisco, activate the scope on the server and that should do it for you.

As far as actually migrating the DHCP database from Cisco to Windows, I don't have any experience with doing that so can't offer you any insight as to whether that's possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

80/20 rule is probably your best bet. see: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958936.aspx

get the windows server up and serving with the correct settings, then swap the proportions after most of the leases have renewed on the windows server.